# Between or Among

Tags: word-choice

This is what Ellen DeGeneres jokingly said in the Oscars this year:

> I did a little bit of research and **between** all the nominees here tonight, you've made 1,400 films. And you've gone to a total of six years of college. I'm kidding. Kids, stay in school.
>
> Meryl has been nominated for an Oscar a total of 18 times. It sounds good, but if you do the math, **between** dresses, hair and makeup, that's hundreds of thousands of dollars.

Can either of these two instances of "between" possibly be substituted for "among"?

Comment: Both............ **between** should be used to choose **between** two options.

Comment: The second example seems really unusual/awkward to me. What he means is *when you **add up** [the costs of]*, but usually in such constructions we use *between* to mean *when you **divide** [some total] **between** [the recipients/constituent parts]*. For a single word in OP's example, I'd use *including* or *counting*, not *between*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Fairly common in AmE ...

Comment: Maybe Ellen isn't so grammatically conscious? But definitely, I don't see her usage of *between* correct. @FumbleFingers, I noticed that you used *he* instead of *she*. Can we use the masculine form of the pronoun for her *gender*? I don't actually know.

Comment: @LesterNubla I'm sure it was a slip of the tongue, or a typo. Ellen is a woman, and *she* is the correct pronoun. I disagree with FF that the second example sounds *really unusual* or *awkward* I understand its meaning and it's something I'd say myself. Although she was presenting the Oscars live, I'm sure the jokes were prepared weeks ahead. Ellen had all the time in the world to hone her lines.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Well, I don't really know Ellen and I don't watch her shows. Maybe you're right. And I think Ellen is smart enough to know her lines, whatever it is.

Answer (score 5):

A few points to bear in mind:

1. This is not writing; this is a native English speaker **speaking** English. Aloud.
2. This is a professional comedian performing comedy. Into a microphone.
3. This is a person being paid hundreds of thousands of dollars to say this. On national TV.

So "correct" is hardly the issue.
In fact, maybe being "correct" isn't such a great idea after all.
So much for "correctness".

As to the original question, only the first example may alternate with *among*

> *and among all the nominees here tonight, you've made ...*

That's a pretty normal usage, summing up a single variable over a multivariate set, and it really doesn't matter whether *between* or *among* gets used, since neither of them is designed for statistics.

The second one, however, is a different usage, and I don't think it works with *among*:

> **among dresses, hair and makeup, that's hundreds of thousands of dollars*

Note that this is **not** a single variable summation -- this is multivariate accounting,
and this refers to the bottom line, not just one row out of many.

My best guess is that it's a shortening and paraphrasing of something like

> *including all the factors - dresses, hair, makeup, etc -- that's hundreds of thousands of dollars*

and *between* got chosen as most obvious preposition, the one that (almost) nobody would notice.

This has, of course, nothing to do with the zombie rule mandating dual *between* vs plural *among*.
But then, that's not really a rule of English anyway.

Comment: Thanks, John. Despite your heads-up about the so-much-for-correctness, Ellen was "correct" in her usage of "between," wasn't she? :) As for the first example, you said either "between" or "among" would do. But if you had to choose, which would you plump for?

Comment: Why ask me if I really meant it? Would you believe me if I told you?

Comment: What's not to believe? :)

Comment: As far as I can tell, you didn't say clearly which is better in the first example. And I think no two different words could be equally acceptable in a given context.

Comment: I didn't really consider the fact that it's a *spoken* context when I first looked at this. I certainly didn't consider the fact that *in some (other) contexts*, "between" encompasses ***two*** objects where "among" would normally be used with ***three or more***. Looking at it again now, I can't think of *any* short replacement for "between" in OP's example #2 that would pass muster for me in a formal written context. In a spoken context I'd almost certainly opt for ***what with***, but I can't help feeling that particular usage sounds more BrE than AmE.